# Arbitrary sampling over an interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline, cubic

I have arbitrary points (8192,4678,1087.2,600,230.4,etc) that I want to interpolate and resample at other define points (100,500.3,802,2045,4399.5125,etc).

I tried cubic spline interpolation but it is using a steady step sampling and depending on the step sampling it may not generate the value I need.

How would you do it ?

Comment: With a spline. That you got something you did not want merely says that you used the spline incorrectly, or that you did not know how to use that capability, or that you simply used a poorly written spline tool. You also have not explained the problem well.

Comment: I assume you have `x` and `y` values, and want to estimate new `y` values for defined set of `x`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your points are `x1=[...]` and `y1=[...]` and you want to evaluate a spline a new base of `x2=[...]` then you

```
y2 = spline(x1,y1,x2)
```

** Example **

```
x1 = [0,2,4,6,8].'
y1 = [24,25,22,14,6].'

x2 = [2,2.5,3,3.5,4].'
y2 = spline(x1,y1,x2)

    y2 =

       25.0000
       24.7227
       24.1563
       23.2617
       22.0000
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the underlying physical phenomenon. There is a fine line between interpolating and just making up stuff.

- I would probably first [upsample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling) & [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) until I have a meaningful signal at a fixed sampling rate.
- I would then use some interpolation method to estimate the signal at the goal points.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to consider doing this backwards.

Rather than generating a lot of points and hoping that the points that you need are there, calculate a formula for the interpolation (perhaps piecewise linear or something more complicated) and evaluate the function at the required points.

Assuming you have `x = [1 2 3 4 10]` and `y = [11 22 13 24 11]` your linear interpolation at point 6 would be:

```
24+(6-4) * (11-24) / (10-4)
```

It should not be too hard to generalize this.